# Suppose that for events $A$ and $B$, we have: $P(A)= 0.3, P(B)= 0.2, P(A \cup B)= 0.7$. Is this possible?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, set-theory

> Suppose that for events $A$ and $B$, we have: $$P(A)= 0.3$$
> $$P(B)= 0.2$$ $$P(A \cup B)= 0.7$$
>
> Is this possible?

We know that: $$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$
$$0.7 = 0.3+0.2-P(A\cap B)$$
$$\therefore P(A\cap B)= -0.2$$

This means that these probabilities are not possible. Is this correct?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Alternatively, $P(A\cup B) \le P(A)+P(B)$ fails.

Comment: Yes it will be impossible as any probability needs to be $\geq$ 0.